# 深層学習における色の学習はされているのでしょうか？

Tags: python, 深層学習

深層学習においてRGB値などで画像を入力した場合、色情報に関する特徴抽出は第1層でしか行われないと思います。しかし、白黒画像から色画像の生成などができています。この点について知見がある方いましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: [此処にある論文](http://hi.cs.waseda.ac.jp/~iizuka/projects/colorization/ja/)は読まれました？多分読んでる前提で回答が来るのでは？と思います。

Comment: 素人なりに調べてみましたが、Computational color constancyというジャンルが相当するんですかね。この分野ではDeep Learningを利用した色の学習を行う研究もあるようです。
Approaching the computational color constancy as a classification problem through deep learning - ScienceDirect
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320316302266

Answer (score 1):

深層学習モデルはただ入力された数字のみを見て積和演算を行なっています。
白黒(1チャンネル)をRGB(3チャンネル)に拡張する際、どのチャンネルのどの位置ににどれだけの数値を配置すれば正解との乖離が少なくなるかを突き詰めていきます。ですので、第何層でどのような特徴量を抽出しているかはブラックボックスです。